# Getting access to "employeeId" or "jobTitle" Claim via Asp.Net Core 2.2 with AzureAd

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, claims-based-identity, claims

I'm trying to extend the claims I get back from AzureAd. I know there's more available, but I have no idea where to start. The documentation is all over the place.

I basically have an ASP .Net Core 2.2 web application configured as follows:

```
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });

            services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));

            services.AddMvc(options =>
            {
                var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                    .Build();
                options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
            })
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
```

When trying to access the claims via code below, I don't get but the standard ones, whilst there are more loaded in AzureAd & Graph.

```
            var claimsIdentity = User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
            ClaimsDetected = claimsIdentity?.Claims.ToList();
```

I already adapted the manifest file with various options, but nothing seems to work. I googled my *ss off - but all documentation is over the place and not consistent or out of date.

Has anyone a working example or tutorial or could anyone tell me how I can enrich my claim set with specific types I found in the graph?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For accessing `jobTitle` from Azure AD to Claims, you will need to get the accesstoken to get `jobTitle` by Graph API.

Detail steps.

1. For getting accesstoken, you need to provide the `ClientSecret` in Azure `App registrations`
2. App Registrations->Your application->Settings->Keys->ClientSecret or any string for Key Description-> Expires for your own scenario-> Copy the generated ClientSecret
3. Startup.cs

   ```
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   {
       services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
       {
           // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
           options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
           options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
       });

       services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
           .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));
       services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AzureADDefaults.OpenIdScheme, options =>
       {
           options.ResponseType = "id_token code";
           options.ClientSecret = "ClientSecret in Azure";
           options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
           {
               OnAuthorizationCodeReceived = async context => {
                   // Acquire a Token for the Graph API and cache it using ADAL. In the TodoListController, we'll use the cache to acquire a token for the Todo List API
                   string userObjectId = (context.Principal.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier"))?.Value;
                   var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(context.Options.Authority);
                   var credential = new ClientCredential(context.Options.ClientId, context.Options.ClientSecret);

                   var authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(context.TokenEndpointRequest.Code,
                       new Uri(context.TokenEndpointRequest.RedirectUri, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute), credential, "https://graph.microsoft.com");

                   // Notify the OIDC middleware that we already took care of code redemption.
                   context.HandleCodeRedemption(authResult.AccessToken, context.ProtocolMessage.IdToken);
                   HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
                   HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me");
                   request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authResult.AccessToken);
                   HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);
                   var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                   // Parse your Result to an Array
                   var jArray = JObject.Parse(result);
                   // Index the Array and select your jobTitle
                   var obj = jArray["jobTitle"].Value<string>();
                   var identity = context.Principal.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
                   identity.AddClaim(new Claim("jobTitle", obj));
                   await Task.Yield();
               },
           };
       });
       services.AddMvc(options =>
       {
           var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
               .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
               .Build();
           options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
       })
       .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks, had to import `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory` package to make it all work, but now it works and I understand why finally. Thanks for taking the time.