# Fetching Employee ID field of logged user using Azure AD

Tags: model-view-controller, oauth, azure-active-directory

We're integrating OAuth into our MVC Web application and it uses employee id field for fetching various reports.

I've used userClaims.Name to fetch the emailid of logged in user as indicated below, and need to get the employee id as well. I am unable to get the employee id using the claim **privatepersonalidentifier** as indicated below

`var userClaims = User.Identity as System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity;
                string id = System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/privatepersonalidentifier").Value;
                GlobalHelpers.EmailId = userClaims.Name;`

It would be great if one of you suggest how to fetch employee id using Claims object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two ways for your reference:

1.Use Claims Mapping feature, just follow [this blog](https://devonblog.com/cloud/azure-ad-adding-employeeid-claims-in-azure-ad-jwt-token/). But this feature is currently in Preview.

2.Use graph api, you can get `employeeId` property by calling the api as below. You will need to get the accesstoken to call it. Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55156150/10504999) for the details.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me?$select=employeeId
```